# Can parallel addition of a bigger capacitor damage the smaller one?

Tags: capacitor, parallel, damage

I have connected big capacitors to the speakers to increase the bass. Now, after months of using, I notice that one of the speakers sounds 2x low. I ejected those big capacitors, still the same.
I don't know how to test the caps. So I'm asking theoretically, could those big caps have damaged the small ones?

Comment: How? Please draw a schematic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlikely, but yes.

A capacitor and the coil of the speaker form an oscillator, which will resonate to some frequencies more than at others. Resonance means you get larger voltages.

Adding resonance to a system can hence introduce voltages that you didn't design for. That can, in turn, break voltage-sensitive components such as capacitors.

Why it's unlikely: The smaller capacitor you used is probably sufficiently robust against overvoltage; also, speaker capacitors tend to be of the self-healing film type, so only a reduction in capacity would be noticable, with should shift the frequency response, but not lead to a reduction in output power with a sensible test signal (I assume that's what you mean with "2x low", whatever that exactly means).

More likely are cabling problems or a damaged speaker.

Comment: Isn't it class D something?

Comment: @GregoryKornblum lost me there, sorry?

Comment: Unless he uses very old equipment, the amplifier should be Class D- switching stage. So no obvious oscillation.

Comment: @GregoryKornblum huh, there's a lot of real-world audio amplifiers that aren't class D, I thought.

Comment: (this wouldn't be about class-X at all, by the way, but about the amplifier having a voltage feedback loop with a bandwidth >> audio bandwidth, right?)

Comment: By "2x low" I meant that one of the capacitors sound two times lower than the other one. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: You mean speaker, right? A capacitor shouldn't make a sound, usually? Or do you have e.g. electrostatic speakers (which are capacitors) and I'm misinterpreting your question?

Comment: and how do you measure "two times lower"? I mean, -3dB SPL? at which frequencies? How did you measure that?

Comment: Big caps in parallel with little caps will form a PI filter, with voltage STEPUP being the ratio of big/little. There is a risk, as Marcus said.